# How to append selected items in WPF c# listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, multipleselection

I want to append all the selected items in listbox. When i am trying the following code i got `"System.Data.DataRowView\r\nSystem.Data.DataRowView\r\nSystem.Data.DataRowView\r\nSystem.Data.DataRowView\r\n"` How to get the actual data?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (object o in lstBoxRoles.SelectedItems)
    {
    sb.AppendLine(o.ToString());
    }
string s = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: What types are the items bound? How did you add the items?

Comment: Could you insert your *xaml* code? I think you do not use bound ItemSource, that's why you get the Control but Content.

Comment: @Lei Yang From database

Comment: We need to see your code. How did the items show the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments: You use *DataTable* and *DataRow* to present data in listbox (I think it is a *DataGrid* or *ListView* btw).

As you see, Selected item contains the whole View of Row.
If your stuff - *DataRow* - has *ToString()* implementation, modify your code:

```
sb.AppendLine(((DataRowView)o).Row.ToString());
```

If you need a specific column to append:

```
sb.AppendLine(((DataRowView)o).Row["SpecColumnName"].ToString());
```